# Variables which can't be accessed in the current scope in C

Tags: c, variables, scope

I've heard about the concept of live variables which can't be accessed in the current scope. The three examples I could think of off the top of my head are:

1. `ptr = malloc(size * sizeof(ptr_type); ptr = different_ptr;`,
2. A static variable inside of a called function which is no longer in scope, or
3. A global variable, which isn't external, in a file which is no longer in scope.

I have two questions about this. Do I understand this concept correctly? If I do, what other examples are there in standard C?

Comment: I guess you could add stack variables in all routines above the one calling yours :)

Comment: I'm not sure the first one really counts, since `ptr` is still a variable it's just pointing elsewhere. What can't be accessed there is really just the memory location, there's no variable left representing it.

Comment: A file which isn't in scope?

Comment: Thread local storage for another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you seem to understand the concept accurately.
2. Nested scopes:

   ```
   void pointless(int x)
   {
       int y = x;
       if (y > 0)
       {
           int x = y + 1;  // This x means the argument is out of scope (hidden)
           if (x > 10)
           {
                int y = x - 10;  // This y hides the previous y
                printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   That's not good code, but sometimes code generators do something less pointless but using nested variable declarations a little similar to that.